# build a page with sub-html-templates - Telerik Icenium Mobile App (Cordova)

Tags: cordova, telerik, icenium

In a Telerik Icenium Mobile App, can I build a page with sub-html-templates like I do with Angular but with standard javascript and html.

For example.

I have a

```
---- index.html and would like to include in it both
     ----- navigator.html
     ----- mainView.html
```

how can I do within a Cordova App?

**Update**

I found the article here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/load-remote#asynchronous-template-loading

but now it is working on my local simulator but on my Android and Web Simulator (which is normally most closely mimics the actual phone experience) it is not.  See below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this blog post that covers using Kendo UI remote views (which is effectively what you need, I think): http://www.telerik.com/blogs/kendo-ui-mobile-remote-views-and-separate-html-files

Comment: Correct, almost, but I'm using this sibling technique "loading remote view async" http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/load-remote#asynchronous-template-loading but now my problem is:

Comment: ... in the simulator I am able to load the remote html via ajax with no issues, however when testing on Android it doesn't load.  Any ideas?  (trying the path stuff now...)

Comment: I wonder if it's an Android permissions issue? Have you enabled network access? Does it work properly on an iOS device?